# Forward all parameters to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

Now I need to take the parameters from the url and put them in the request, but is there a way to do this automatically. i.e. putting all url parameters in request and forward to the jsp without writing code like below?

```
private ActionForward managementView(ActionMapping actionMapping, ActionForm actionForm,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    request.setAttribute("param1", request.getParameter("param1"));
    request.setAttribute("param2", request.getParameter("param2"));
    request.setAttribute("param3", request.getParameter("param3"));
    request.setAttribute("param4", request.getParameter("param4"));
    .....

    return actionMapping.findForward("managementView");
}
```

Comment: It depends on the application, of course, but in a lot of common Java web application frameworks, this can open up a big security hole. Request attributes are set by the application; they are often assumed to be trusted information. Automatically conferring this trust on any parameter an attacker submits in the request could be dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting forward="true" in  corresponding struts-config.xml file's forward .

This http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=181 can help you provide the details regarding the same.

Answer (score 0):

Se if that works for you

```
   protected void setRequestParameters(HttpServletRequest req) {
        Enumeration<String> requestEnumeration = req.getAttributeNames();
        while(requestEnumeration.hasMoreElements()){
            String paramName = requestEnumeration.nextElement();
            req.setAttribute(paramName, req.getAttribute(paramName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am looking for something that would do this in the background. I'm thinking there must be some property or flag that when turned on would do this in the background